# Why does only one of my cats use the 'Litter Robot'?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have two cats and I recently got a new litter robot. Per the websites suggestions I put the litter robot next to the old litter box and stopped cleaning it to entice my cats to use the robot instead.

One of my cats has began using the robot but the other ended up pooping in my bathtub instead of the robot. I tried keeping him in the room for an hour with the robot so he’d be less afraid of it but he still wouldn’t go inside it. I left it switched off for about 3 days and I added their old litter to it.

I’m afraid if I clean out the old litter box that both cats will go back to the box, but I’m also afraid that if I take away the old litter box completely my one cat will continue to poop in the shower or in the corner somewhere.

Comment: For anyone else wondering what a 'Litter Robot' is, here's the link to the manufacturers website: https://www.litter-robot.com/gb/en/

Comment: I have 2 cats also. The male jumped right in the second it had sand in it! My little girl however will have no part of it. I tried all the tricks...Once I realized she was no longer minding the robot I even shut it down then removed "her" box hoping she would cave and just use the robot lol but it has been a solid no go! What a shame!!! But what can ya do? I love the robot! But hate now having 2 friggen boxes AND it's too late to return the robot because I have already had it now 2 or 3 months already trying to get kitty 2 into it. I am a frequent scooper ... I went from having one very tidy b

Answer (score 7):

I got the litter robot too and my cat took a few weeks before using it. It may take some time for the cat to realize it’s a litter box, up to several weeks.

Did you leave the litter robot turned off at the beginning to not scare them when it turns? Another tip is to add a bit of the old litter to the robot so he can recognize that it’s a litter box. You can also place treats near it to get your cat accustomed to the litter robot.

It’s better that you leave the old litter box in place to not stress your cat, and so he doesn’t get used to pooping in the bathtub.

Comment: Yes I left it off for about 3 days and I added their old litter to it. My one cat doesn’t want to get any treats near the robot. I will clean up their other litter box and see if it helps

Comment: I would say to keep cleaning the old litter box and trying to give him treats near the robots. If after one month he doesn't use it, he will probably never use it.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the one cat hates the litter robot. You may have to accept that you won't be able to use it. Cats have preferences just like humans. You wouldn't force a human to use a thing they absolutely hate, and so too, if the cat hates it that much, you should relent. On the positive side, by all accounts I've heard, the self-cleaning boxes aren't all they're cracked up to be. Sure, you don't have to scoop all the time, but the mechanisms get disgusting, and it's a difficult and onorous chore to try to clean those.

Another option is to use both, but keep the robot far from anything the one cat needs access to. That way, you could be saved some work, but the one cat will still have the box it wants. The other cat will likely use the litter robot when the other box is not clean, because most cats prefer clean boxes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen with my two cats. I broke down and continued to use the old litter box in addition to the robot. I “think” it’s a territorial issue. The one cat that uses it guards it with his life. When I moved the old litter box right next to the robot the one that uses the litter robot began using both. When I put the litter box in a totally different area than the robot, they both seemed happy again with no accidents. The afraid cat is curious about the litter robot and will always peek in but will not get in. Cats! ‍♀️